# Compare 2 List without pattern matching required

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

As stated from the question, right now I would like to compare 2 List of variable without pattern matching

1st List Variable = userList[i]

2nd List Variable = colors_code[i]

**For example,**

**userList[i]** will contains **'Y','B','G','R'**

**colors_code[i]** will contains **'R','G','B','Y'**

I want my code to compare this 2 List variable for string exist, not pattern matching

**Below are my code:**

```
        # Create a For-Loop to loop 4 times, since we have only 4 colors
        for i in range(0, 4):

            # To validate User Input & overwrite User Input into the List
            if userList[i] == colors_code[i]:
                count = count + 1

                userList[i] = "1"
                correct[i] = userList[i]

            else:
                continue
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

If number of occurrence is important

```
sorted(['Y','B','G','R']) == sorted(['R','G','B','Y'])
```

Otherwise

```
set(['Y','B','G','R']) == set(['R','G','B','Y'])
```

Comment: I have tried using 

set(['Y','B','G','R']) == set(['R','G','B','Y'])

In my code, which will be set([userList[i]]) == sorted([colors_code[i]])

I noticed that if both set doesn't have the same matching, the result will be disappear from the output.

Any solutions?

Comment: `sorted([colors_code[i]]) ` isn't set. so you're comparing apples and oranges. On the other hand `sorted` sorts the given iterable (lets say a collection). so `sorted([colors_code[i]])` doesn't have a meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one approach to ensure that all elements of a list are contained in another list:

```
# Classic way:

flag = True
for e in list1:
    if e not in list2:
        flag  = False
        break

if flag:
    # whatever


# Using all function:
all(map(lambda e: e in list2, list1))

# Using frozen sets
FrozenSet(list1) == FrozenSet (list2)
```